# Git submodule foreach with selected or limiting submodule list

Tags: git, github, version-control, foreach

**Issue in Brief :**

I am just wondering whether git provides any options to limit the submodules while looping (ex : git submodule foreach "git pull origin master")

*I need like this :*

```
  git submodule foreach --limit_from="submodule_2"  --limit_to="submodule7" "git pull origin master"
```

**Issue in Detail :**

I am working on a project with 24 submodules configured, i am facing the following issues which has a serious impacts in the entire team productivity,

Since its a six member team and the development goes rigorously, We used to pull the remote 3 to four times a day,

> git pull origin master && git submodule foreach "git pull origin
>   master"

***Some times***

```
1. we miss to clear/reset the repository before
2. miss to commit the changes before git pull
3. miss to checkoout the correct branch in the submodules
4. may get a auto merging conflict errors
```

The above may suppress the git pull most of the time.

**Example** : Let us consider the git status shows the following ,

```
#   modified:   lib/library/submodule_repo_1 (new commits)
#   modified:   lib/library/submodule_repo_2 (new commits)
#   modified:   lib/library/submodule_repo_3 (new commits)
#   modified:   lib/library/submodule_repo_4 (new commits, modified content)
#   modified:   lib/library/submodule_repo_5 (new commits)
#   modified:   lib/library/submodule_repo_6 (new commits)
#   modified:   lib/library/submodule_repo_7 (new commits, modified content)
.
.
.
.
.
#   modified:   lib/library/submodule_repo_23 (new commits, modified content)
#   modified:   lib/library/submodule_repo_24 (new commits)
```

**The above git status shows :** Out of 24 submodules `submodule_repo_4` , `submodule_repo_7` and `submodule_repo_23` have modifications.

`git` will throw an error if i missed to clear these changes or commit them before a `git pull`.

**Pain taking job :**

Let us consider if i commit the modification in `submodule_repo_4` and `submodule_repo_7` but not the `submodule_repo_23`, in this case git will update all the repository upto `submodule_repo_22` and it will throw an error (**Ex** :local file changes will be overwritten by merge) after reaching submodule_repo_23.

> So to update the submodule_repo_23 after a git reset or commit, i need
>   to loop again the submodule from the begining say submodule_repo_1.

**Do we have any option to limit the submodules inthe foreach loop like below,**

```
git submodule foreach --limit_from='submodule_repo_20' --limit_to='submodule_repo_23' "git pull orign master"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can except submodules you do not want to process.
It means that foreach will still enter the submodule but will skip the command execution:

```
git submodule foreach '[ "$path" = "library/PhpExcel" ] || git status'
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Unexpectedly running command in all submodules.

Comment: @ufukomer are you sure you copied the correct name of the existing submodule to the filter '"$path" = "name" ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an update based on @Eugene's answer.

According to git submodule's documentation, it seems the path of a submodule is now held by the `$sm_path` variable.

I was willing to run a command in each submodule in a specific path, so here's what I did :

```
git submodule foreach -q '[[ ! "$sm_path" == begins_with_this_path/* ]] || echo $name'
```

Note the `*` at the end of the path.

Of course you can replace `echo $name` with whatever you need.

Comment: This does not work for me: git version 2.34.1